# Npgsql.PostgresException (0x80004005): 42703: column {schema} of relation {table} does not exist

Tags: postgresql, c#-4.0

I am trying to update a table in postgresql from C# .NET. getting error column {schema} of relation {table} does not exist, but at the same time I can able to select the table.
the user given the access other than super user. could you please help here?

I tried , direct execute of update in pgadmin tool for the same table and it is successful

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing the SQL statement.

Comment: here is the query {UPDATE schema.table SET schema.table.name = $2,  WHERE schema.table.id = $6}

Comment: Here query is building with dapper in C# .net, the problem i think is we have schema.tablename added to columns.

Comment: but at the same time Select schema.table.name from schema.table is working fine